# Navigation on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I want to remove class "open" when it's hovered over the area outside of "parent". How to do so?
Here is my pen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aVJapG

I'm trying to make a navigation that drops on hover.

Here is my js:

```
    function hover(tab) {
  showAndHiddenOthers(tab.id);
}

function showAndHiddenOthers(id) {
  for (var i = 0, len = document.getElementsByTagName('li').length; i < len; i++) {
    if (id[id.length - 1] == i + 1) {

      document.getElementById('p' + (i + 1)).style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('tab' + (i + 1)).style.backgroundColor = '#3cf';
    } else {

      document.getElementById('p' + (i + 1)).style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('tab' + (i + 1)).style.backgroundColor = '#3c9';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: working well , what is issue?

Comment: I want to hide the content (p) when it's hovered outside of parent. Basically imagine a menu and if you hover outside of menu it's closed.

Comment: one issue you'll have with that is the gap between the top items and the popup ... to get to the popup you have to "leave" the "parent", which will hide the popup